Requesting SMS permission in Expo / React Native
I am trying to request SMS permission using Expo/React Native. It works when requesting camera permission, but when it comes to SMS, it doesn't work. I also added READ_SMS in the AndroidManifest.xml, but that’s not working either.


const requestSmsPermission = async () => {
    if(Platform.OS == 'android') {
      const smsPermissionAndroid = await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.READ_SMS')
      if(smsPermissionAndroid == false) {
        try {
          const request = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS,
            {
              title: 'SMS Permission',
              message: 'SMS Inventory App needs access to your messages.',
              buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
              buttonPositive: 'OK',
            }
          )
  
          if (request === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log('Passed');
          } else {
            console.log('Not Passed.');
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err);
        }
      }
    }
 }



